# Why does `go test -run NotExist` pass?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

If I run the following

```
go test -run NotExist
```

The response is PASS. Seeing as my test file does not contain a test called `TestNotExist` I would expect the command above to return FAIL

Comment: Because the all the tests you specified, which was none, passed, or in other words you had no test failures.

Comment: That behaviour doesn't really make sense, I would expect it to say something like "Test 'NotExist' not found"

Comment: It's just the behavior everyone has agreed upon. It's often how you run benchmarks without executing any tests, or check for test compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `-run` option `go test` runs all tests. You use the `-run` option to *not run all tests*; to *filter out*, to *exclude* tests (and you do this in the form of *requiring* names of non-excludable tests to *match* a regexp pattern - but this is irrelevant form the point of discussion):

[Command go, Test packages:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages)

> By default, go test needs no arguments. It compiles and tests the package with source in the current directory, including tests, and runs the tests.

[Description of testing flags:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags)

> ```
> -run regexp
>    Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression.
> ```

It is a perfectly "normal" outcome that a filtering filters out all tests, that no tests remains in the set of tests that still need to be executed.

When no tests FAIL, it is considered as the test run PASSes. If no tests match, no tests will run and no tests will FAIL, and thus the test run will PASS.

Comment: Thinking about this again the behaviour does make sense. I've heard it said that you can't prove the absence of errors. You can only test for their presence. If nothing fails explicitly then assume it's working. The thing that annoys me is that if I made a typo in the command I won't get a warning.

Comment: @mozey Agree. But a simple `go test` will reveal errors, and that is what you should use to test / validate. You should only use the `-run` option if you want to quickly test some changes.