# Go test specific file ouput

Tags: testing, logging, go, printing

I'm new in Go and trying to work on a project.
The structure of the code is like

```
handlers/
  -time.go
  -time_test.go
```

I've already tried go build, make (project) name

The thing is, I want to add some console output inside the code so that I know if a branch is covered or not (or for debugging). Right now, it doesn't work for me.

If I use:

```
go test -run test_file_path
```

If will just output

```
Pass        0.009s
```

Even I put`t.Log("print log")` or even `fmt.Print("Say Hello")` inside the test function.

If I just use `go test -v test_file_path` I would have undefined variables. The build & test would fail.

Any suggestions? Thanks!g

Comment: Did you try the option *-cover* ?

Comment: Related: [Why does `go test -run NotExist` pass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463609/why-does-go-test-run-notexist-pass)

Answer (score 0):

Just `go test ./handlers -v`. The **handlers** is the package path.